# Authenticate to LXD rest API over network , certificate auth keeps failing

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, google-chrome, x509, lxd

I am trying to access LXD REST API over the Network.

Followed  : [Link to Doc](https://stgraber.org/2016/04/18/lxd-api-direct-interaction/).

1. `lxc config set core.https_address "[::]:8443"`
2. `lxc config set core.trust_password <some random password>`
3. `curl -s -k --cert ~/.config/lxc/client.crt --key ~/.config/lxc/client.key https://127.0.0.1:8443/1.0/certificates -X POST -d '{"type": "client", "password": "some-password"}' | jq`

As stated [Here](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/rest-api.md) the official REST API Doc.

`GET to / is allowed for everyone (lists the API endpoints)`

But on pointing the Browser (Chrome) to

- `http://<server-ip>:8443`
- `https://<server-ip>:8443`

Both result in `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`.

Added the `client.crt` to Windows 10 certificated, via Chrome > Settings > Manage Certificated and Import.

Tried it with POSTMAN

Still the same issue.

Works all fine , when access from inside the server.

`curl -s -k --cert ~/.config/lxc/client.crt --key ~/.config/lxc/client.key https://127.0.0.1:8443/1.0 | jq .metadata.auth`

The above command works fine.

My understanding of certificate based auth is very limited. Any pointer would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Going thru a lot of trial and errors. I have finally stumbled upon this [Link](https://github.com/aarnaud/lxd-webui/blob/master/readme.md). It's part of Configuration of LXD works just perfectly. Below are the steps I followed.

Install `ZFS` , `LXD` and then do `sudo LXD init` to get the normal configuration done.

After that,

### Configuration of LXD

1. `sudo lxc config set core.https_address [::]:8443` , it can be your port of choice.
2. `sudo lxc config set core.https_allowed_origin "*"` Ideally replace the start with the domain from with the API would be accessed. `*` would make it accessible from everywhere.
3. `sudo lxc config set core.https_allowed_methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"`
4. `sudo lxc config set core.https_allowed_headers "Content-Type"`
5. `sudo service lxd restart # sometimes is required`

---

### Setting up of Authentication Certificate (Self Signed)

1. `mkdir lxd-api-access-cert-key-files`
2. `cd lxd-api-access-cert-key-files`

This is just to keep the files related to authentication in a separate directory.

---

1. `openssl genrsa -out lxd-webui.key 4096` , this would generate a private key for you.
2. `openssl req -new -key lxd-webui.key -out lxd-webui.csr` , This would create a certificate request.
3. `openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in lxd-webui.csr -signkey lxd-webui.key -out lxd-webui.crt`. Generate an auto signed certificate.
4. `openssl pkcs12 -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -export -in lxd-webui.crt -inkey lxd-webui.key -out lxd-webui.pfx -name "LXD WebUI"` , This would export the keys in `.pfx` format that can be used inside browser for authentication.
5. Now download the `lxd-webui.pfx` file. Locally.
6. Import the file to the browser.

   1. [Chrome Linux](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1215006-install-pkcs-12-file---linux-ubuntu-using-chrome)
   2. [Chrome Windows](https://www.comodo.com/support/products/authentication_certs/setup/win_chrome.php#import)
   3. [FireFox](http://www.digi-sign.com/support/client%20certificates/import%20firefox)
7. `lxc config trust add lxd-webui.crt` Tells LXC to use this certificate for auth.

### Testing

- Now Close and Start your browser again.
- Point your browser to `https://[serveri-ip]:[port-defined-earlier]/1.0/networks`

This should give a response similar to below,
`{"type":"sync","status":"Success","status_code":200,"operation":"","error_code":0,"error":"","metadata":["/1.0/networks/lo","/1.0/networks/ens33","/1.0/networks/lxdbr0"]}`